# Predictive observation density of stochastic volatility model

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Consider the stochastic volatility state space model

$x_{t} = \phi x_{t-1} + a_{t}, \; a_{t} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\tau^2)$

$y_{t} = \text{exp}(x_{t}/2) \; e_{t}, \; e_{t}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$

I know the observation density $p(y_{t}|x_{t}) = \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2 \text{exp} (x_{t}))$.

I want the predictive observation density $p(y_{t}|x_{t-1})$. Could anyone please help deriving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$
p(y_t|x_{t-1}) = \int p(y_t|x_t)p(x_t|x_{t-1})dx_t
$$
with $x_t|x_{t-1} \sim \text{Normal}(\phi x_{t-1},a_t)$. It's a weird scale mixture of normals. It doesn't have a closed form.